# significancy of method, url, queries of OAuth

Tags: http, oauth

1. if a protocol (OAuth influenced) uses only `timestamp`, and `nonce`,
2. And the server strongly check those two factors,
3. Is it (can it be said) safe omitting `request method`, `request URL`, and `query parameters`?

I have a custom HTTP protocol influenced a lot from OAuth.

```
some-NAME: unencrypted information for identifying client and locating the shared secret key
some-INIT: iv
some-CODE: AES256-encrypted information; timestamp and nonce are in here
some-AUTH: Hmac with SHA512 for CODE before encrypted.
```

When server-side checks only `timestamp` and `nonce`, is it safe?
Is it ok for some `replay attack`s or some `bastards-in-the-middle-attack`s?

UPDATE -----------------------------

This protocol actually authorizes the mobile devices. And personel authentication is an optional addition.